# Unsatisfied Link Error (No such file or directory) on Linux, while file is available at given path

Tags: path, java, shared-library

I am loading some .so files in my Java code using `System.load("home/projects/proj/my.so")`. Where I have given complete path of my `.so` files. But in my logs I am getting below error:

```
sys:Err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'home/projects/proj/my.so'
home/projects/proj/my.so : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Native library (linux-x86-64/home/projects/proj/my.so) not found in resource path ([])
```

**Same code is working fine in windows and if I create a environment variable to this path. Everything starts working fine.** So not able to understand why it's saying `No such file or directory`?

I have gone through multiple articles, but no help.

Comment: `path/my.so` is a relative path, relative to the current directory.  What is the current directory, and where is the library located in relation to this? You may watn to switch to using an absolute path?

Comment: Here path is the absolute path to that library. I have actually passes the complete absolute path.

Comment: You say you can run this on Windows. Is that with _the same_ `.so` file, or is the file on Linux recompiled for Linux?

Comment: For windows I have created .dll files. Those are picked up correctly. But here my concern is that when I create a environment variable to same path. It starts working fine. And I can't create environment variable every time (due to some other issues).

Comment: What environment variable? Is there an issue with setting this variable when running your Java code?

Comment: One question to you, as you mentioned absolute path, so the absolute path should be linux-x86-64/home/projects/proj/my.so or home/projects/proj/my.so? Currently path which is being passed is home/projects/proj/my.so. (And when set this home/projects/proj/my.so to environment variable it's working fine).

Comment: No environment variable is being set correctly. I am creating an environment variable to same location home/projects/proj/my.so. @Kusalananda edited my question path to make it more clear.

Comment: The path that you edited in is also relative (does not start with `/`).

Comment: Thanks for help. I got it. I am new to Linux so was not aware about dependency of '/' in relative and absolute path in linux. Thanks for help.